# Use Effect is not firing on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using MUI DataGrid with server side rendering. I have state for my page setUp and my fetchData function should be getting recalled everytime I update the pageState.page or pageState.pageSize attributes. Unfortunately when I move pages or change the page size, nothing happens and I don't get new data. I put a console.log in my fetchData function and it looks like it's not firing at all when the state changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [pageState.page, pageState.pageSize]);
```

```
<StyledDataGrid 
            rows={data} 
            columns={columns}
            rowCount={pageState.total}
            loading={pageState.isLoading}
            pagination
            page={pageState.page - 1}
            pageSize={pageState.pageSize}
            pageSizeOptions={[3,5,10]}
            paginationMode="server"
            onPageChange={(newPage: any) => setPageState(old => ({...old, page: newPage + 1}))}
            onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize: any) => setPageState(old => ({...old, pageSize: newPageSize}))}
            initialState={{
              pagination: {
                paginationModel: { pageSize: pageState.pageSize, page: pageState.page -1},
              },
            }}
            onPaginationModelChange={setPaginationModel}
            paginationModel={paginationModel}
            />
```

I've tried to adjust the values of the object directly instead of making a  new object but that didn't work either. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: What is responsible for changing the page size or page number? Is it the component that calls `StyledDataGrid`? Is it the `StyledDataGrid` itself? Is it both?

Comment: So the StyledDataGrid is a styled component using MUI DataGrid, the page change is a prop I saw in a tutorial but after some testing I don't think its working so I think my issue may just be that my props aren't set up correctly so the state isn't actually changing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still quite unsure about what is responsible for changing the page state. I would remove the change handlers from `StyledDataGrid` and just pass it the numeric values of `page` and `pageState`, and have the mechanism for changing these values *outside* of `StyledDataGrid`.

For example:

```
function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Page or page size changed");
  }, [page, pageSize]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Increase Page</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPageSize(pageSize + 1)}>Increase Page Size</button>
      <StyledDataGrid page={page} pageSize={pageSize} />
    </div>
  );
}

function StyledDataGrid({
  page,
  pageSize,
}: {
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{`Page: ${page}`}</span>
      <br />
      <span>{`Page Size: ${pageSize}`}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Personally I avoid using the setState callback (`setState(old => ...)`) unless i need to, so in my example, since we already have the current state in scope, I just use that.

I've also decided to store `page` and `pageSize` in two separate states, but you can continue to store them in a single object state if you'd rather.